# Rescale dygraph data on x-axis zoom

Tags: javascript, dygraphs

I am showing a cumulative time series using the `dygraphs` library in javascript.

I would like the y-axis values to rescale to the new origin of the graph so it always shows as starting at zero (basically just add an offset to the whole series).

Is that possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the "rebase" extra, check out [this demo](http://dygraphs.com/tests/straw-broom.html).

```
<script src="extras/rebase.js"></script>
```

and:

```
new Dygraph(
  document.getElementById('div'),
  data,
  { plugins: [rebase] }
)
```

Comment: And you got me the `synchronizer` extra in that example as well. Perfect ! Is there documentation on all the `http://dygraphs.com/extras/` somewhere ?

Comment: Not really. But you can take a look at the source: https://github.com/danvk/dygraphs/tree/master/src/extras.